# What is an attribute in Java?

Tags: java, attributes

I read that to get length of an array, I use the `length` attribute, like `arrayName.length`. What is an attribute? Is it a class?

Comment: Are you sure you're not thinking of Javascript?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

An attribute is another term for a field. It's typically a public constant or a public variable that can be accessed directly. In this particular case, the array in Java is actually an object and you are accessing the public constant value that represents the length of the array.

Answer (score 8):

A class is an element in object oriented programming that aggregates attributes(fields) - which can be public accessible or not - and methods(functions) - which also can be public or private and usually writes/reads those attributes.

so you can have a class like `Array` with a public attribute `length`and a public method `sort()`.

Comment: It's a good example, except in Java arrays aren't instances of `Array`, and there's no `addElement` method on arrays. Arrays in Java are instances of an internal class, which exposes a constant `length` field.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I just picked the first thing that crossed my mind on the method example. But I wasn't trying to be that accurate, maybe I should though.

Comment: @JSeven the example is good, but if you could edit your answer to provide a more accurate one it would be better. :)

Answer (score 5):

Attribute is a public variable inside the class/object. length attribute is a variable of int type.

Answer (score 4):

Attributes is same term used alternativly for properties or fields or data members or class members.

Answer (score 3):

An attribute is an instance variable.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, "attribute" simply means a data member of an object.

Answer (score 2):

Attribute is a synonym of `field` for `array.length`

Answer (score 2):

Attributes are also data members and properties of a class. They are Variables declared inside class.

Answer (score 2):

A class contains data field descriptions (or properties, fields, data members, **attributes**), i.e., field types and names, that will be associated with either per-instance or per-class state variables at program run time.

Answer (score 0):

An abstract class is a type of class that can only be used as a base class for
another class; such thus cannot be instantiated. To make a class abstract,
the keyword abstract is used. Abstract classes may have one or more
abstract methods that only have a header line (no method body). The method
header line ends with a semicolon (;). Any class that is derived from the base
class can define the method body in a way that is consistent with the header
line using all the designated parameters and returning the correct data type
(if the return type is not void). An abstract method acts as a place holder; all
derived classes are expected to override and complete the method.

Example in Java

abstract public class Shape

{

double area;

public abstract double getArea();

}

Comment: The question is about **attributes** in Java

Answer (score 0):

Attributes are the characteristics of the class that help to distinguish it from other classes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

■ **What is an attribute?**

– A variable that belongs to an object.Attributes is same term used alternatively for properties or fields or data members or class members

■ **How else can it be called?**

– field or instance variable

■ **How do you create one? What is the syntax?**

– You need to declare attributes at the beginning of the class definition, outside of any method. The syntax is the following:
        ;